# PHP SQL Column = Column minus $value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I know how to add value  within the SQL Query
So current value of Bank = Bank + Value

```
UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank + '$deposit' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'"
```

As Example if $deposit = '500' so string/text =  500
and Example Bank value is 1000 it is 1500 right.
Now i try to substract with current value.

```
UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank + '-500' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'"
```

Should be working.
What not works is:

```
UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank + '-' + '$deposit' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'"
```

or

```
UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank + '-$deposit' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'"
```

What should i do?

Alright i've sold it myself, thanks for everyone that tried to help, ya'll brought me on the idea of the answer :

```
UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank +- '$deposit' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'
```

instead of only using

```
-
```

ive used

```
+-
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please use [prepared statements](http://us3.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: if you are trying to concat the strings.. then dont use +.. use CONCAT()... if you are trying to do math you need to change it to an int so you can do the calculations

Comment: I try to Update the Value of the Column   Bank into current value of Bank minus the value of $deposit in PHP.

Comment: If `Bank` is a numeric value, use numbers not strings (i.e. `Bank - 500` rather than `Bank + '-500'`)

Comment: @p.s.w.g So you say to use    Bank = Bank - $deposit     ?

Comment: @Mr.Morgan No. See my earlier comment. Use a prepared statement, e.g. `Bank - :amount`. Using string manipulation makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `-` for subtraction:

```
"UPDATE users SET Bank = Bank - $deposit WHERE Username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'"
```

Comment: That's what i've said, it is not working.
Edit: Oh i've never said that. But still it doesn't process it.

Comment: You shouldn't put numbers in quotes, although I think it should automatically unquote them.